# U-tube containing two liquids and accelerating in a horizontal direction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

Say I have a U-tube of constant cross-sectional area $A_C$ whose arms are at a distance $L$ apart from each other. The tube contains two different liquids $A$ and $B$ that don't mix, and at first the height of liquid $A$, relative to the line where the two liquids separate, is $h_a$, as shown in the drawing. Now, I'm told that if the tube is caused to move in a horizontal direction with constant acceleration of magnitude $a$, the height of the liquid in the right arm of the tube, relative to the line of separation between the liquids, goes down ($h _{a _{f }} $ in the drawing). This makes intuitive sense to me, but I'm also told that the following relation holds in this accelerated scenario:

$$F _{1 }-F _{2 }=m a   ,  $$

where $F _{1 }=P _{1 }A_C  $ is the force exerted by the column of liquid in the left side of the tube on the mass of liquid $A$ lying along the bottom of the tube, $F _{2 }=P _{2 }A_C  $ is the force the column of liquid in the right arm of the tube exerts on that same horizontal mass of liquid $A$, and $m =\rho _{A }A_C L $ is the mass of liquid $A$ at the bottom of the tube.

[image: U-tube with liquids]

[image: Forces acting on horizontal mass of liquid]

I cannot for the life of me understand why this is the case. Doesn't the equation above, drawn from Newton's Second Law, imply there is a pressure gradient causing the liquids to flow downwards in the left arm of the tube, rightwards along the bottom, and upwards in the right arm? The way I understand it, however, the liquids inside the tube are **not** moving through the tube, although the system as a whole is accelerating. There *is* a net force on the horizontal mass of liquid (it is accelerating with the rest of the system), but this net force can't originate from any pressure differences within the tube, or else liquid would flow inside the tube. Rather, the *external force* causing the tube to accelerate must contribute to the acceleration of the horizontal mass of liquid.

As for the pressures inside the tube, some force must be opposing them and preventing liquid from flowing from one end of the tube to the other. I've tried explaining that to myself in terms of the ficticious force experienced by the liquids. This force, whose magnitude is $m a  $, points to the left along the bottom of the tube and should oppose the increase in pressure in the left arm of the tube. So, from the point of view of the tube, one has

$$F _{1 }-F _{2 }-m a =0  $$

and things seem to work out. Is this reasoning correct? How can I understand this situation without examining it from a non-inertial frame of reference? I have attached an image of the original problem in case it is necessary. Thanks! [image]

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question not a "do my homework for me" question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you just had the horizontal arm of the tube. Suppose there is no friction. The tube and liquid are accelerating to the right. Their velocities are the same. The liquid stays fixed with respect to the tube.

You would have to exert a force on the end of the tube to make the liquid keep up with the tube. You could apply a force at both ends, so long as the force at the left end was bigger. The net force must add up to the right amount to keep the liquid accelerating at the same rate as the tube.

In the U shaped tube. Those two forces come from the weight of the liquid in the two vertical arms.

Comment: Does this mean that the liquids inside the tube _are_, indeed, accelerating due to a pressure difference, only an outside observer doesn't perceive it because the tube is accelerating at the same rate?

Comment: Generally you want to talk about forces from the perspective of an inertial frame of reference. You can use an accelerated frame, but it is more complicated and less intuitive. You need to talk about fictitious forces. So you should look at this from the point of view of an outside observer.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by an outside observer not perceiving the acceleration of the fluid. You see a car accelerating. Do you not also see the driver accelerating?

Comment: Yes, there is a pressure gradient along the horizontal section of the tube. Consider the force you have to apply at the left end of the tube to accelerate the horizontal column. Now consider the force you need to apply to the center of the tube to accelerate the right half of the horizontal column. Less fluid, so less force.

Comment: It is the motion of the liquids along this pressure gradient that seems to me to be imperceptible from the perspective of an inertial frame of reference. If it were perceptible, shouldn't we see the liquids flow downwards in the left arm, to the right along the bottom, and upwards in the right arm? Instead, we only see the horizontal acceleration of the system as a whole. According to your answer, the net force from the weight of the liquid columns accelerates the horizontal liquid so its acceleration matches that of the tube. That's why we don't see liquids moving in the tube. Is this right?